# How can I set the ui dropdown to show the first item when running the game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UiDropdown : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Use these for adding options to the Dropdown List
    //Dropdown.OptionData m_NewData, m_NewData2;
    Dropdown.OptionData[] m_NewData;
    //The list of messages for the Dropdown
    List<Dropdown.OptionData> m_Messages = new List<Dropdown.OptionData>();
    //This is the Dropdown
    Dropdown m_Dropdown;

    public GameObject[] gameobjects;

    void Start()
    {
        m_NewData = new Dropdown.OptionData[gameobjects.Length];
        //Fetch the Dropdown GameObject the script is attached to
        m_Dropdown = GetComponent<Dropdown>();
        //Clear the old options of the Dropdown menu
        m_Dropdown.ClearOptions();

        for (int i = 0; i < gameobjects.Length; i++)
        {
            m_NewData[i] = new Dropdown.OptionData();
            m_NewData[i].text = gameobjects[i].name;
            m_Messages.Add(m_NewData[i]);
        }

        //Take each entry in the message List
        foreach (Dropdown.OptionData message in m_Messages)
        {
            //Add each entry to the Dropdown
            m_Dropdown.options.Add(message);
        }
    }
}
```

The script is attached to a Dropdown ui object.

The problem is that it's clearing the options and then where running the game there is no selected item and if I will try to select the first item it wont select it I will need to select first another item and then I can select the first item.

And if I will remove the clearing options line it will select the first item but also will add all the items twice.

This screenshot is when the clearing options line exist:

[image: Clearing]

If I will remove the clearing options line:

```
m_Dropdown.ClearOptions();
```

Then:

[image: Clear]

What I want to do is when running the game the first item in the dropdown will be selected. Now it's or empty or the whole items added twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `RefreshShownValue` after adding everything.